# How to get the ServletContext in Rest web service

Tags: java, jersey

I am implementing rest web service using Jersey. I need to have object of ServletContext to save the file in the application directory. Please help me to get the context.

I am calling this webservice from android device.

Thanks in advance.

```
@Path("notice")
public class NoticeResources {

    @Resource
    private ServletContext context;


    @POST
    @Path("uploadphoto")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String uploadNotices(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream) {

        File photoDirectory = new File("\\photo");

        // if the directory does not exist, create it
        if (!photoDirectory.exists()) {
            boolean result = photoDirectory.mkdir();  
            if(result){
                System.out.println("DIR created");
            }
        }

        String rootPath = photoDirectory.getAbsolutePath();

        String uploadedFileLocation = rootPath + "\\photo.jpg";
        // save it
        try {
            writeToFile(uploadedInputStream, uploadedFileLocation);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            return "no" + rootPath;
        }
        return "yes" + rootPath;
    }

    // save uploaded file to new location
    private void writeToFile(InputStream uploadedInputStream, String uploadedFileLocation) throws Exception {
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(uploadedFileLocation));
        int read = 0;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

        out = new FileOutputStream(new File(uploadedFileLocation));
        while ((read = uploadedInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            out.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }   
}
```

Comment: It's paradoxical to use context in a REST API. The context should be immutable.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use @Context, here is Jersey [documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html#d0e2021)

```
@Context
private ServletContext context;
```

UPDATED - you can also inject directly into methods if desired

```
public String uploadNotices(@Context ServletContext context, ...)
```

Comment: +1 I believe it can be injected into methods as parameters as well (at least in RESTEasy this is possible, Jersey should be the same).

Comment: You're correct it can, I didn't include it since it wasn't asked explicitly in OP question - but I'll include it.

Comment: whats the import for @Context?

Answer (score 3):

use the annotation @context (Method level injection)

```
public Response getContext(@Context HttpServletRequest req, @Context HttpServletResponse res)throws Exception
{   
    System.out.println("Context Path is:"+req.getRequestURL().toString());
    result=req.getRequestURL().toString();
    return Response.status(200).entity(result).build();
}
```