# Store boolean between two web services rest (JAX-RS Jersey)

Tags: java, json, rest, web-services, jersey

I call first web service and before to return json response, i want to save one variable (boolean) in memory

this variable is retrieved in second webservice as this :

```
// First class REST service
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public HealthResponse health(@Context HttpServletRequest req, @Context HttpServletResponse res) {

HealthResponse response = new HealthResponse();
......
status = callMethodForStatut();
// Store it for to use in onther REST

return response;
}
```

Second REST service :

```
// Second class REST service

    @GET
    public void check(@Context HttpServletRequest req, @Context HttpServletResponse res) { 

    // Read status stored in first REST call
    boolean status = ....
    ....

    }
```

Is it possible to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the variable status as a field in the class itself. It can retain the value of previous call if the same instance of the class is being used by framework you use. Or it can be declared as static field.

Better approach is to store the value in ServletContext and use anywhere in the application. The answer shows the usage: [How to get the ServletContext in Rest web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17379286/how-to-get-the-servletcontext-in-rest-web-service)